# Pandas - Line Graph Subplots with Multiple Indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I want to create line graph subplots with each Code per Customer having it's own subplot in a separate file for each customer.

```
          Date    Code  Customer     Purchases
1    6/22/2016   6-BZt     Piggy             8
2    6/22/2016   7rTPn     Piggy             1
3    6/22/2016   Hb4vZ     Piggy             1
4    6/22/2016   L0xs5     Piggy            94
5    6/22/2016   S5cLN     Goose             2
6    6/22/2016   k4Yp5     Goose             1
8    6/21/2016   6-BZt     Goose             8
9    6/21/2016   7rTPn     Piggy             1
10   6/21/2016   Hb4vZ     Piggy             1
11   6/21/2016   L0xs5     Piggy            94
12   6/21/2016   S5cLN     Goose             2
13   6/21/2016   k4Yp5     Goose             1
```

I tried

```
lineSess = lineSess.set_index(['Date', 'Customer', 'Code'])
lineSess.unstack().plot(subplots=True)
```

but it's not outputting the way I want.

Comment: A few questions: (1) by separate _file_ do you mean separate _figure_? (2) so do you mean you want 2 figures with 6 subplots each because that is the number of unique codes? (3) I assume you want the number of purchases to be the y axis, but what is the x axis supposed to be?

Comment: 1) Yeah I meant figure. Whoops.
2) Exactly.
3) X-axis is the Date range

Answer (score 0):

So I think the order of operations you'll want to go with is to first split your dataframe into separate dataframes for each Customer, set the index, and then unstack and plot. Given an arbitrary number of customers you can do something like this

```
lineSess.sort_values(by='Customer', inplace=True)
lineSess.set_index('Customer', inplace=True)

# get list of unique customer names
customers = lineSess.index.unique().tolist()

# create an empty dataframe for each customer name
customer_dfs = {k: v for k, v in zip(customers, [pd.DataFrame()]*len(customers))}

# fill the empty dataframes with the data corresponding to each particular customer
for key, df in customer_dfs.iteritems(): # customer_dfs.items() for python-3.x
    df = lineSess.loc[lineSess.index==key]
    df = df.set_index(['Date', 'Code'], drop=True)
    df['Purchases'].unstack(level='Code').plot(subplots=True, title=key)
```

These plots will look rather dull with the data you provided since the number of purchases does not change from one day to the next. But assuming that this is only part of your dataset, the plots may be much more informative.